# An idiom for "as far as it is related to me,..."

Tags: idioms, expressions

### Scenario #1:

Let's suppose a top student is going to give a speech at school and would like to express his gratitude to his teacher for all his efforts in one educational year.
I was wondering how he can imply that message just for himself (not on behalf of the other students)?

I know the idiom: "[for one's part](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/for+one%27s+part) which means:

- As far as is related to, regards, or concerns someone; to the degree that someone is involved or a part of (something).

But surfing the internet, I could not find this structure with "thanking someone". For instance does the sentence below sound natural to you?

> I would like to thank you **for my part**.

This is why I think there should be either something wrong with this idiom or the way you normally use it.

### Scenario #2:

Let's say, a group of people do something wrong. Later, one of them wants to express his own attitude regarding his wrongdoing and indicate his sorrow and regret (regardless of what the other people who committed the same action in that group would feel.) Is this idiom applicable here?

> I feel sorry **for my part**.

Or there is any better idiom for these two situations? If so, please kindly let me know about it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

### Scenario #1

Your sentence doesn't really work. You could say something like

> I would like to thank you for all the help you have given me this year.

If it is a speech to a larger audience you could word it

> I would like to thank Mr X for all the help he has given me this year.

Both of which exclude any efforts he may have put in on behalf of other students.

### Scenario #2

That is fine.

> I feel sorry **for my part** in the wrongdoing [or specify the event].

It is usually "*for my part **in***" something.